# Google Analytics Cross Domain with CoreCommerce

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I would like to setup cross domain tracking. Google says the code on the the first domain should look like this.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['example-2.com'] );
```

For example-2.com, my URL looks like this:

```
https://www15.corecommerce.com/~mystore897/checkout.php?m=fastcheckout
```

Should my code look like this now?

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['www15.corecommerce.com/~mystore897/checkout.php?m=fastcheckout'] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to put in the domain of the secondary domain that you are tracking into

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['corecommerce.com']);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Here is some more info on the autoLink plugin: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autolink

Comment: unfortunately, I can't install my tracking code in the 3rd party main domain "corecommerce.com". I only have access to put code there www15.corecommerce.com/~mystore897/checkout.php?m=fastcheckout

Comment: Can you please clarify your question and what you are trying to accomplish? Which domains are you trying to track across?

Comment: Ok I'm trying to share sessions between store.mywebsite.com and a 3rd party domain at www15.corecommerce.com/~mystore897/checkout.php?m=fastcheckout

Comment: @kenold, that you have access only  to the subdomain should not matter.  The autolinker appends the cross domain parameter to outgoing links to the linked domain, and www15.corecommerce.com is of course within the corecommerce.com-Domain. So you can just use the code as suggested by nyuen.